# File Upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload image using code-igniter, but it's not possible, why I don't know. Can anyone help me?

[image: "I will print $_FILES array "]

**Here is code I have tried**

```
 public function upload(){
 $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploads/"; 
 $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png|jpeg|gif"; 
 $this->load->library("upload" , $config);

 $rs = $this->upload->do_upload("userfile"); 
 print_r($rs); 
 print_r($_FILES); 

if(!$rs){ 
$error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view("main_view", $error); 

}
else{ 
$file_data = $this->upload->data(); $data['img'] = "localhost/FileUpload/assets/uploads/";
$file_data['file_name']; $this->load->view("success_msg" , $data); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your file upload input has to have name=userfile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to actually test this of course, but I believe this will get you started.

```
public function upload() {

  $name = 'something'; // set this based on your requirements, I often use random strings or user names according to the situation. 

  $config['upload_path']   = "assets/uploads/"; 
  $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png|jpeg|gif";
  $config['file_name']     = $name;

  $this->load->library("upload" , $config);

  $rs = $this->upload->do_upload("userfile"); 

  print_r($rs); 
  print_r($_FILES); 

  if(!$rs) { 
    $error = array( 'error'=>$this->upload->display_errors() );
    $this->load->view("main_view", $error); 
  }
  else { 
    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
    $file_name = $file_data['file_name'];
    $ext       = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Useful to store your name in database if/when you need to
    $data      = array('upload_data' => $upload_data);
    $this->load->view("success_msg" , $data); 
 } 

}
```